# Replacing firefox driver with htmlunit driver

Tags: css, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, selenium-firefoxdriver

Hi can any please tell how to run this sample program with HTMLUNIT DRIVER INSTEAD OF FIREFOX DRIVER.
The below code had run successfully with firefox driver but did not run successfully with htmlunit driver giving

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using `.//*[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' gssb_e ')]`-EXCEPTION.

```java
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class GoogleSuggest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");

        WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        query.sendKeys("Cheese");

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 50000;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)
        {
            WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_e"));
            if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed())
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        List<WebElement> allSuggestions =
        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='gssb_a gbqfsf']"));
        for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions)
        {
            System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Please any one tell me how to do it with HTMLUNIT driver n I M A VERY JUST BEGINNER and explain me the reason even and i would be happy if any one post the same code manipulated with HTMLUNIT driver and also please tell me how to overcome the DEFAULTCSSERROR when using HTMLUNIT driver which was again not a problem with firefox driver.

My main intention is dat running the above process backside with out invoking the browser making all things invisible.

Any one please do help me in this aspect.

Comment: Your error message does not even match up with what code you are running. **No where** in your code **at all** are you running `.//*[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' gssb_e ')]` ...so please put your **actual** code in the question and expand what is this "DEFAULTCSSERROR" you are talking about? When did it happen? What line?

Comment: Arran the code i have posted is correct and i am getting the same error when i replaced the firefoxdriver with htmlunitdriver in the above code.OK let me explain my need precisely -the output i got executing the above code in netbeans is cheesecake factory
cheesecake factory menu,
cheesecake recipe,
cheese,
cheesecake,
cheesecake factory nutrition,
and so on,
........ ,         and my desire is dat i want the same output using HTMLUNIT DRIVER REPLACING WITH FIREFOX DRIVER.If u can plz post the same code with HtmlUnit driver as such same output is obtained.PLZ HELP it z very important for me.

Answer (score 1):

In HtmlUnit Driver, It'll look for only lowercase tag and attribute.

Example :
Html

> input type="text" name="example" >
>
> INPUT type="text" name="other" >

// webdriver code

> driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input"));

for HtlmUNit case:It'll find only one element(name="example")

for firefoxDriver case = it'll find 2 element

hope it'll you in debugging code

Answer (score 0):

**HtmlUnit driver <> FirefoxDriver**

```
"If you test javascript using HtmlUnit the results 
      may differ significantly from those browsers"
```

Take a look [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver)

Comment: e1che i tried with HtmlUnitDriver enabling javascript but i was unable to get the same output as i m getting with firefox driver in the above program.If u can plz post the same code with HtmlUnit driver as such same output is obtained.PLZ HELP.